# When can kashrut certification be withheld?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

In today's news (11 Dec 2018):  "Rabbis from the Vaad HaRabanim of Flatbush, which grants kosher certification, threatened to pull their  supervision of the Garden of Eat In and Orchidea if [a certain] Orthodox lesbian comedian performed at either venue."

Question: Do rabbis have the halachic right to refuse kashrut certification to an establishment for reasons that have nothing to do with the kashrut of food?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think they don't have a Halakhic right to not certify anyone they want for any reason? What could obligate them to certify anyone?

Comment: I could have sworn I've seen this discussed here before... Maybe I'm confusing this with other venues, since I can't find a duplicate. But it's definitely debated whether a Kosher supervision is intended to supervise the establishment as a whole is just the food.

Comment: Would you ask the same question, if the waitresses at these establishments were very scantily dressed (topless)?

Comment: @Double AA -- I would have thought a Vaad would have the obligation to certify anybody who asks, if food requirements are met.  Otherwise, could they just refuse it if they don't like the race, or the politics, or the national origin of the requestor?

Comment: @Mauice Sure! Why would race or politics or national origin matter to Halakha at all?? (They might have to follow US laws in their business, but the details of that are not for here.)

Comment: @IsraelReader Sure! Why would that affect the Kashrut of the food at all?? It obviously could be a nudist resort and still serve Glat meat. Even trans fats, tobacco and alcohol can be certified kosher despite they're poisonous nature. I'm not sure certifying food served near a lesbian performer is ethically any worse than publicly publishing a list of "approved" liquors. The latter will surely lead to way more sin.

Comment: There's a YUTorah shiur about this -- afraid I don't recall the title off-hand. R' Ovadiah Yosef discussed a multi-tier system, ranging from "just the food" to "the whole venue." But this was a matter of debate, with some feeling there was implicit endorsement of the venue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Vaad of Queens' policy was (is?) that if it's open during normal hours to the public, they have the right to ask about the general atmosphere. If it's a private event for only those invited, then the certification is just on the food.

Comment: Keep in mind some environments mean that a mashgiach can't be there ... which means there are no guarantees on the food. A wedding in Israel performed by a Rabbanut rabbi is supposed to finish well before Shabbos and serve kosher food -- the environment shouldn't be hostile to the officiant.

Comment: One mashgiach affiliated with my local Va'ad and another person affiliated with the OU have told me several times - "The majority of the decision going into the certification of a product or establishment is politically based." That's not disqualifying or minimizing that the food kashrut is ignored. However, even if the food has kosher ingredients, the kashrut orgs. decision to certify or not, at that point, is a combo of personal as well as "political" factors. E.g. - they can refuse cert. if you charge more for the food than a competitor.

Comment: @DoubleAA To me, kashrut certification means that the establishment is kosher to patronize. Glatt Kosher belly dancers doesn't sound too kosher.

Comment: @IsraelReader I see you've never read a Kashrut certificate before. You should check one out. Besides, more than 50% of the population can sit near belly dancers without Halakhic problems, and it's not like pure Vodka is too kosher to drink. Or is "drink responsibly" a Halakhically valid disclaimer?

Comment: @DoubleAA FYI - In NYC at least, many places are certified despite receiving a failed helath grade from the NYC health Dept. with the failing reason "mouse droppings, rats and roaches found in food area." Last I heard, mouse droppings and roaches ain't kosher. Forget about the health hazard and that it's gross. Yup, it's a bit of a mystery as to why such places can remain kosher certified with such conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Kashrus certification agencies are legally-recognized (according to local law) entities whose business is the certification of the kosher status of restaurants, food-processing plants, etc. Restaurants hire these agencies (i.e. pay them money) to supervise the preparation and cooking of food and to publicly state that they have done so and that the aforementioned preparation and cooking was done in accordance with the laws of kashrus according to the agency's well-known standards.

This is a purely business relationship whose terms are no different than any other business relationship. Unless the contract between the two businesses specifies that the agency will never withdraw certification for any reason other than kashrus violations (which would be an extremely burdensome stipulation, which seems unlikely that any agency would agree to), the agency should certainly be able to terminate the business relationship within the bounds of *halakha*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Kashrus consists of two parts - the Kashrus of the ingredients and the supervision of the process of food preparation. For example, Kosher Milk and Kosher meat, but supervision is needed to check they are not mixed, or it is Bishul Israel etc.
2. Rabbis have the rights to withdraw their [constant] supervision for any reason as this is just a service they provide for the place, thus rendering the place unsupervised and therefore uncertified - notice I didn't say not-Kosher, even if the ingredients are the same.
3. Concerning the financial agreement between them - it all depends on what has been agreed on, if the Rabbis violated it they can be sued for the damages.